Having problem with importing the PyMuPDF library
I'm tryng to import the pyhton library PyMuPDF
and after i installed it, vscode give me this error
(
Import "fitz" could not be resolved
)
I'm a beginner so maybe i made some beginner error...
i tried to check if the library was installed by terminal and it said yes

This has changed recently and now allows to do any of the formats import pymupdf, import fitz (for backward compatibility, and import pymupdf as fitz (if you do not want to changed every occurrence.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

if you can share more about your code

You could use import pymupdf instead of import fitz.
According to the tutorial of PyMuPDF:

Old versions of PyMuPDF had their Python import name as fitz. Newer
versions use pymupdf instead, and offer fitz as a fallback so that old
code will still work.

By the way, you need to check your python interpreter. This warning is provided by Pylance. You could use shortcuts Ctrl+Shift+P and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your python interpreter which you installed the PyMuPDF in.
